# How to change size of figure with subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, layout, subplot, figsize

I'm having some trouble trying to change the figure size when using `plt.subplots`. With the following code, I just get the standard size graph with all my subplots bunched in (there's ~100) and obviously just an extra empty figuresize . I've tried using `tight_layout`, but to no avail.

```py
def plot(reader):
    channels=[]
    for i in reader:
        channels.append(i)

    plt.figure(figsize=(50,100))
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(channels), sharex=True)
    
    plot=0    
    for j in reader: 
        
        ax[plot].plot(reader["%s" % j])
        plot=plot+1

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you construct the `channels` list, but never use it? Also, your `for` loop over `reader` is a perfect use case for `enumerate`. E.g., `for plot, j in enumerate(reader):`.

Comment: I use the channels list to extablish how many subplots there will be. thanks for the tip on enumerate

Comment: If you can't do `len(reader)` or `len(list(reader))`, you could always just do `N_channels = len([1 for _ in channels])` since you don't need to store the actual contents of `reader`.

Comment: docs for subplots: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can remove your initial `plt.figure()`. When calling `plt.subplots()` a new figure is created, so you first call doesn't do anything.

The subplots command in the background will call `plt.figure()` for you, and any keywords will be passed along. So just add the `figsize` keyword to the `subplots()` command:

```
def plot(reader):
    channels=[]
    for i in reader:
        channels.append(i)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(channels), sharex=True, figsize=(50,100))

    plot=0    
    for j in reader: 

        ax[plot].plot(reader["%s" % j])
        plot=plot+1

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, the `figsize=(50,100)` is what I'm here for.

Answer (score 2):

The figure size is in inches. If for whatever reason, the figsize of subplots needs to be changed after plotting (perhaps because its creation is handled by an external library such as `statsmodels` etc.), then you can call `set_size_inches()` on the figure object to set the figure size.

```py
fig.set_size_inches(50, 100)
# or 
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(50, 100)
```

---

A working example:

```py
import random
def subplots():
    xs = [[range(3)]*2]*2
    ys = [[[random.random() for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(2)]
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2)
    for i, row in enumerate(zip(xs, ys)):
        for j, (x, y) in enumerate(row):
            axs[i][j].plot(x, y)

subplots()                          # draw subplots
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(15,5)     # set figure size afterwards
```

---

Another example where a time series decomposition plot is handled by `statsmodels`. Without setting figure size post-plotting, the resulting figure is too small:

```py
import random, pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

data = pd.Series([random.random() for _ in range(100)], index=pd.date_range('2020', periods=100, freq='D'))
decomp = seasonal_decompose(data)
fig = decomp.plot()
fig.set_size_inches(10,10)
#   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       <---- set figure size to (10, 10)
```